# Ensure a class in notnull in Scala?

Tags: scala, null, non-nullable, scala-2.11

Since the NotNull trait is being deprecated, what is the new best way to declare my classes not nullable?

There is still the compiler option (does not prevent someone from misusing my libraries in other projects).  Along with the handful of conflicting Java annotations that I doubt the Scala compiler will respect.

Comment: Neither the ScalaDoc nor the source code (for 2.10.x) indicate `NotNull` is deprecated.

Comment: @RandallSchulz It's deprecated since 2.11 (which is not yet released).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `null` in Scala at all, and if you don't, it's not necessary to use the `NotNull` trait.

If you have values or variables which can have "no value", use the `Option` type instead of the `null` value. `Option` has two subclasses: `Some` and `None`.

```
// text is "None", which means it has no value
var text: Option[String] = None

// Use "Some" when it should have a value
text = Some("Hello World")
```

`Option` has lots of useful methods; it can (more or less) be treated as a collection that has zero or one elements, so you can call common collection methods on it and you can use it with pattern matching.

```
text match {
  case Some(s) => println("Text: " + s)
  case None    => println("Empty")
}
```

Comment: I don't use null in Java either.  I want to prevent other people from using null.

Comment: Using `null` isn't idiomatic Scala, so in general Scala programmers will not use `null`.

Comment: Creating bugs isn't idiomatic Scala either - but they still happen.

Comment: Not using null at all is nice, but sometimes you need to interact with libraries that do, such as the Scala standard library. Regex example: "foo(.*r)?".r.unapplySeq("foo") == Some(List(null))

Comment: @aij That is strange behaviour, I would consider that a bug. Please consider [reporting it as a bug](http://scala-lang.org/contribute/bug-reporting-guide.html).

Comment: @Jesper I'm assuming redesigning the API in a way that would break backwards compatibility falls outside the scope of a bug... There's a reason Scala supports null.

Comment: @aij Scala mainly supports `null` for interoperability with Java. Prefer using `Option` (`Some` and `None`) instead of `null` in Scala code.

Comment: `assert(x!=null)` here and there to be safe